# How can I change the content of the preloaded js files on a static website to be specific to my browser only?

Tags: javascript, web, static, preload

How can I change the content of the preloaded js files on a static website to be specific to my browser only?

Thanks

Can i use tampermonkey or how i use it?

Comment: In the server side, inspect the `User-Agent` header. That will tell you the client's browser and with that, serve the appropriate bundle.

Comment: I dont have access to server for now